# Gitlab CI only triggers the job if it is related to a merge request, carry on release tag and it comes to master branch

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to initiate a job in Gitlab CI only if it matches the following conditions:

1- belongs to master branch

2- carries a release tag

3- output of a merge request

Technically, by protecting the master branch, the commit to master will be through merge request only, so number 3 should be addressed. However, when it comes to number 1 and 2 together, I couldn't find any "AND" operation, and it looks like the default behaviour is "OR", so the following doesn't work as I want to:

```
jobDeploying:
   stage: deploy
   only:
      - master
      - tags 
   script:
      - echo "Deploying the code"
```

I cannot use `except` here as I cannot predict what all the branch names are. We may have tons of feature branches,  `develop` and `master` are pre-defined, but I don't know the list of all feature branches. I feel like what I am looking for is not so special, and it will be required to ensure that the release tag is associated with the code that ends up in production. Any workaround on an alternative approach to having the same outcome is more than welcome.

Comment: What you probably want are rules, where you can define a custom trigger, (where branch = master and tag exists) you can write custom logic using this, where you can even define what the release tag regex is https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

Comment: @lindluni It appears that rule has not been added to Gitlab.com. Are you sure it works?